# CGContextRef gives Error

Tags: ios, cgcontextref

i am using `CGContextRef` to draw one horizontal bar and above-below of bar i am displaying text using `drawInRect` method of `NSString`.Here is code:

```
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();//set frame for bar
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = prevWidth;
        frame.origin.y = heightBar;
        frame.size.height = heightOfBar;
        frame.size.width = 10;

        UIColor* color = [ColorArray objectAtIndex:i];
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, borderColor.CGColor);

        CGContextFillRect(context, frame);
        CGContextStrokeRect(context, frame);
        [nameString drawInRect:frame1 withFont:font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

When i call second time it gives me error like:`<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0`.Please help me.Thanking you.

Comment: what do you mean with "when you call second time"? The first time you use it it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says the context is invalid .So i suppose calling the second time means you are calling the method directly i guess.

As per docs

> The current graphics context is nil by default. Prior to calling its
>   drawRect: method, view objects push a valid context onto the stack,
>   making it current.

The context will be valid only in `drawRect:` method.You need to call `-setNeedsDisplay` on the UIView to update the contents